# json_encode codeigniter pass array to view

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I would like to pass a json encoded array to the view in codeigniter

```
public function test() {
    $arr = array(
        "first_name" => "Darian",
        "last_name" => "Brown",
        "age" => "28",
        "email" => "darianbr@example.com"
    );
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

The ajax request in the view:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test",
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.first_name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just need only array in the response of the Ajax. I think no rendering the view is required.

Answer (score 0):

Better try this one:

```
 public function test(){
      $arr = array(
            "first_name" => "Darian",
            "last_name" => "Brown",
            "age" => "28",
            "email" => "darianbr@example.com"
          );
          echo json_encode($arr[0]);
    }
```

Array starts 0 .

and on your view:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "test",
  dataType : 'json',
  success :function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: `$arr` is associated array and accessing its index rather using its key say `first_name` will work?

Comment: yes, it will if you want access` first_name`. try it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the URL, on ur ajax request, u are only refering to a function not the class (Controller) that contains that function.

Right now i'm building an application that uses a lot of ajax request and the way i do it is this way.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //if u have the js functions on another file (not in your view)
    //u can create a variable on the header like var baseUrl = <?=base_url()?>
    //and url would be like: baseUrl + 'MyController/myFunction'
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>MyController/myFunction",
    dataType : 'json',
    success :function(data) {
        alert(data.first_name);
    }
 });
```